# Get Twitter OAuth token and secret without making user sign in using Twitter

Tags: ruby, api, twitter, oauth, token

I've implemented Omniauth for Twitter in a rails app I'm working on. With the users who sign in using that I can get OAuth tokens and secrets for them. That's all working.

What I can't figure out is how to get OAuth tokens and secrets for users who don't sign in using Twitter?

I'm sure I've used sites where you can "Authenticate" them so that they can get OAuth tokens and secrets for you without signing in using Twitter. Twitter seems to suggest that you need to use 3-legged authorization but I can't seem to find anything much about that.

Is 3-legged authorization the way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is modify your controller action that handles the Omniauth callback for Twitter. If when that action is accessed the user already has a session (i.e. they logged in through your alternate mechanism) then you just grab the Twitter token/secret and store it just like you do when creating a new user that signed in via Twitter. If there is no user in the session, then do what you already are doing.

Now, you can just add a button to your site that people who are logged in but do not have Twitter token/secret can see. The button links to the exact same `/auth/twitter` you use for your sign in with Twitter link.

After they authenticate with Twitter they will be sent to the callback URL where your app will see they are already signed in (the user is in the session) and will just add the Twitter token/secret.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I was looking for.